# How to get javascript array to jsp page

Tags: javascript

I am posting my javascript array to a jsp page by using $.ajax() ,

```
var a = {}; a['c0'] = 1; a['c1'] = 2;

// or    

var a = {}; a.c0 = 1; a.c1 = 2;

// or    

var a = {
    c0 : 1,
    c1 : 2 
};

$.ajax({  url: "feedbackaction.jsp",   data: a,   type: 'post',   
          success: function(data) {    alert(data);   } });
```

Now,How can I get this array at my Jsp page ? when I am using request.getParameter("a") ,it's showing that as "null" value.Kindly help.

Comment: You don't have an array. That is an object. An array has numerical indexes and is created with `[]`, not `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
request.getParameter("c0");
request.getParameter("c1");
```

You should get parameters individually.

And, `a` is not an array. It's an object. You can't use an array as a data of `$.ajax`.